# Django DiscoverRunner not running syncdb

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I've been unable to find an answer anywhere else regarding this.

I'm trying to run unit tests on my project which uses South for schema migration. I've already set SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False in my settings. However when I run my unit tests, I get errors about tables missing.

From my understanding of the Django DiscoverRunner, it *should* (according to the Django 1.6 docs) run syncdb after creating the test databases. However, I don't see this happening. Further, I don't even see any reference to syncdb or even 'sync' in the Django test code. The only reference I see is to the post_syncdb signal.

Has anyone encountered problems with syncdb not running when running Django tests?
Or does anyone know where in the Django codebase it should be running syncdb during tests, because I can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: are you using django >= 1.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. It was totally unrelated to the test suite.

I have a custom DB router in my project and was using:

```
def allow_syncdb(self):
    return False
```